# org-clock-sum but excluding child time?

Tags: org-mode

`org-clock-sum` gets the time logged for a header and all of its children. Is there a way to get the time logged ONLY for the top level header (but not its children?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by top level header you mean the outline level 1:

```
(org-clock-sum nil nil (lambda ()
                         (= (org-outline-level) 1)))
```

Otherwise:

```
(save-restriction
  (org-narrow-to-subtree)
  (let ((level (org-outline-level)))
    (org-clock-sum nil nil (lambda ()
                             (= (org-outline-level) level)))))
```

See the third argument of the `org-clock-sum` function:

> Headlines for which HEADLINE-FILTER returns nil are excluded from the
>   clock summation.